# iOS number of displayed lines in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, interface-builder

I have a UILabel that can display up to 2 lines of text. I am not using Autolayout. In IB, I have set the "lines" property to 2. How can I get the number of displayed lines in Obj-C?

Answer (score 0):

In a gist: call the **sizeWithFont:** of the UILabel, and divide by **lineHeight** of the font.